# Using VLOOKUP with a union of columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the dummy table below, I can use the formula below to lookup a value in the third column:

```
=VLOOKUP(1, Table1[A]:Table1[C],3)
```

I am wondering if there is any way to define the lookup range as just column-A and column-B using a union operator?

The formula works fine - the motivation for using only two columns is when working with more complex tables that may change, I would always know that the lookup index is 2.

[image]

Comment: not sure I understand.  You want to look in either A or B to find a match and return the value in C?

Comment: What does "Union operator" mean in this context? Why not just stick with the range reference you have now? Is this not working? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @JNevill see edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is, no, there is no way to do two disconnect columns.

So we do:

```
=VLOOKUP(1,Table1[A]:Table1[C],COLUMNS(Table1[A]:Table1[C]),TRUE)
```

Now it will count the number of column that that range reference encompass.  In your example it would be `3`, if another column is added between it would be `4` thus always referring to the correct column.

[image]